# Failed to compile react hooks()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I am having problem after using the usestate()Hook for state manipulation.

Failed to compiled errors:

```
./src/App.js
  Line 6:43:   React Hook "useState" is called in function "app" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
  Line 14:39:  React Hook "useState" is called in function "app" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.

This errors is showing in my terminal also:

Could not open App.js in the editor.

The editor process exited with an error: spawn sublime_text ENOENT.

Comment: Did you read the error?

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow. Please provide the code where you are using these hooks so we can see what is incorrect. You most likely do not use them in an actual react component.

Answer (score 1):

The [rules of hook plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react-hooks) uses naming conventions to tell what is a component, what is a hook, and what is a regular function. Functions beginning with a capital letter are assumed to be components. Functions beginning with `use` are assumed to be hooks. Your function apparently is named `app`, which is neither, so it's assumed to be neither.

Assuming `app` is a component, the fix is to change its name to `App`.

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to config a hook and did not know about it.

Answer (score 0):

Hello it's maybe an error Because inside Page naming conventions are wrong if you are using the name of your component like `const app = () => {}` just change this to `const App = () => {}` make sure component Name starts with Big letter , hopping this answer helps you